# Startup Multichain in WIndows Task Scheduler

Tags: blockchain

I run command:

> multichaind mychain -deamon

to start up the multichain program. 
As per: https://www.multichain.com/developers/creating-connecting/

I'm running on Win 2012.  I have tried putting this in a startup script using Windows Task Scheduler so that when the machine reboots, it will restart.

The task scheduler history shows it ran successfully, but it's not running. When I run the command

> multichain-cli mychain getinfo

it says it cannot connect to the server. 
And of course, that same command works when I start up multichain in a separate command prompt window.

My theory is that the command runs, but then the command windows is closed, but needs to remain open.  Is there any way to do this, or debug what is going on?

I tried adding the parms as:

> mychain -daemon >>d:\Software\Multichain\log.txt

hoping that it would write to the file so I could read it. But no file was created.

Update: I tried the .cmd file approach as recommended in the comment:

```
multichaind mychain -daemon 
pause
```

That doesn't make sense to me because the first line should never finish.

It did create the log.txt file, but the whole thing still ran and quit in a few seconds:

```
d:\Software\Multichain>multichaind mychain -daemon  1>>d:\Software\Multichain\log.txt 

d:\Software\Multichain>pause  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: If you want the cmd window to remain open, use Task Scheduler to open a batch file, which in turn runs your command. eg: https://superuser.com/questions/644119/how-to-keep-cmd-open-after-task-schedule

Comment: Thanks, tried that (I will update in question in just a minute).  The pause didn't seem to do anything, and beyond that, the multichaind with the daemon option itself should be similar to pause.  Almost like starting mySQL or something, it runs forever until cntl-break out.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming issue then I'm afraid.  You might want to try SuperUser, or does the software have its own support forums?

Comment: SuperUser didn't have any blockchain related tags.  I'll check on multichain forums.